# Elvis "if" operator in Kotlin as function default argument

Tags: kotlin

I was wondering, is this possible in Kotlin and if so, what is correct syntax for it?

How can I modify function argument so:

1. it's possible to pass null value
2. to check, if null is passed -> then `name = ""` else `name = name`

What to do?

```
fun simpleFunction(name: String?) {
      ...
}
```

I tried

```
fun simpleFunction(name: String? = null ? "" : name) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I'd just write `val name = name ?: ""`, you get a shadow naming warning, but it's the best workaround I found out so far for reassigning `val` arguments without a variable name change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible at least in this way, because a default parameter is only applied when no argument is passed at the function call site.

You can try to do one of the following:

- Perform this check inside the function body

  ```
  fun simpleFunction(name: String?) {
      val actualName = name ?: ""
      ...
  }
  ```
- Create a separate function overload that accepts nullable values:

  ```
  @JvmName("simpleFunctionNullableName")
  fun simpleFunction(name: String?) = simpleFunction(name ?: "")

  fun simpleFunction(name: String) { // name is not-null
      ...
  }
  ```